Powershell script failing to identify file
After the Crowd Strike debacle I have multiple Windows servers that have large .dmp files I am attempting to delete.  I have come up with that attached powershell script with no success.   I have tried using the admin share path as well with no success. I have tried removing the variables and typing out the path and each time it returns, "Path does not exist." I have also attempted running in an admin console, rebooting the server to make sure the file isnt still in use, I have manually deleted the same file without issue.  I am at a loss.   Can someone that knows more about Powershell than myself help?  Please.  I sincerely appreciate any assistance.
$computers = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\Computers.txt

$filePath = "C:\Windows\memory.dmp"

foreach($computer in $computers){
    if (Test-Path -Path $filePath) {
        Remove-Item -Path $filePath}
       
    else {
        Write-Host "Path does not exist"}
        }

The output:
PS C:\Windows\system32> $computers = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\Computers.txt

$filePath = "C:\Windows\memory.dmp"

foreach($computer in $computers){
    if (Test-Path "C:\Windows\memory.dmp") {
        Remove-Item "C:\Windows\memory.dmp"}
       
    else {
        Write-Host "Path does not exist"}
        }
    
    
Path does not exist


No matter what I try I get the same result, the file does not exist.  I have validated that it does in fact exist.

Did you mean Test-Path "\\$Computer\C$\Windows\memory.dmp" ?

Assuming SMB, your code should be:
$computers = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\Computers.txt
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $path = "\\$computer\c$\Windows\memory.dmp"
    if (Test-Path -Path $path) {
        Remove-Item -Path $path
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "File does not exist in '$path'"
    }
}

Assuming PowerShell Remoting (WinRM), your code should be:
$path = 'C:\Windows\memory.dmp'
$computers = Get-Content -Path C:\temp\Computers.txt
Invoke-Command $computers {
    if (Test-Path -Path $using:path) {
        Remove-Item -Path $using:path
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "File does not exist in '$env:ComputerName'"
    }
}


I was attempting SMB instead of WinRM.  Even running your updated script, I get the same result that the file does not exist.  Im going to attempt to use powershell remoting and see what I get.

I may have left out some information.  I am attempting to delete a memory dump file that is utilizing much of the storage on many servers but not all.  I was attempting to pull a list of hostnames from a txt file, then loop through each server one at a time to identify and delete that specific file from a remote administrative server.  I wanted to iterate through each server and if the file did not exist, ouput text leting me know that the file did not exist on that server.  I was adding as single hostname of a server for which the file does exist.  i am getting an error that it doesnt exist.

@jesseholden ok, I don't see how this additional information changes anything on my answer. the 2 easiest techniques to remove a file remotely are shown in this answer
